# git checkout newer branch

Tags: git, commit, git-checkout

I switched to a older commit with: `git checkout $HASH` to look for something i did in an older version of my directory. Now i want to go back to the newest commit, but i cant find the Hash for that anymore? when i do a `git log` it just shows the older commits from the commit i am currently at. How can i switch to the newest commit again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to git checkout previous branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout <branch>`, e.g. `git checkout master`.

Comment: `git checkout HEAD` won't work, the head is already detached.

Comment: @Adam: you're right, deleted that. My testing was sloppy, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Use the name of the branch on which you worked before

```
git checkout [branch]
```

If for some reason you don't know the name, you can find the previous position in the reflog

```
git reflog
```

It gives you a list of commits on which you worked in the past, where the first position is the most recent one.

Comment: Also: `git checkout -`, which is short for `git checkout @{-1}`. The `@{-N}` syntax means “Nth most-recent checkout”.