# Where does git store the last checked out branch?

Tags: git

When I do `git checkout -`, git checks out the last branch I had checked out. Where is that information stored?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It scans `.git/logs/HEAD` (the reflog for `HEAD`) for the last line looking like :

```
checkout: moving from <branchA> to <branchB>
```

the "last branch" is `branchA`

---

As said [in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207542/86072) linked by @SergioTulentsev :

> `git checkout -` is a shorthand for `git checkout @{-1}`.

- `@{-1}` is the `branchA` of the last `checkout: ...` line
- `@{-2}` is the `branchA` of the previous to last `checkout: ...` line
- etc ...