# Programmatically get the revision that git will jump to with `git checkout -`

Tags: git

If I use `git checkout -`, git will jump back to the revision I was in before. This is true if it was a detached HEAD (in which case HEAD will be detached in the same revision) or a branch (in which case HEAD will go back to being on that branch).

I would like to be able to know the revision I was just in, the one git will jump to if I run that, ideally, without actually changing HEAD.

So if HEAD was last in a branch, I'd like to get the name of that branch; and if it wasn't, I'd like to get the SHA of that commit.

Comment: What do you mean by "know the revision", exactly? Print? Save to a shell variable? Use as part of a Git command? Something else?

Comment: I want to use it as part of a command in a git alias, so ultimately It'll be printed as part of that command

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch/7207542

Answer (score 3):

`@{-1}` corresponds to the revision of interest. From the `git-checkout` man page:

> You can use the `@{-N}` syntax to refer to the N-th last branch/commit checked out using `git checkout` operation. **You may also specify `-` which is synonymous to `@{-1}`**.

(emphasis mine)

However, whether or not you can recover the name of the branch (if any) that was last checked out is unclear to me. The `git-reflog` man page mentions that

> the `HEAD` reflog records branch switching

but Git doesn't appear to provide any functionality to tap into that information...

Comment: So how can I use that to get the name of the branch I was in? I can get the commit hash with `git rev-parse @{-1}`, but not the branch name (if I was in a branch; `git symbolic-ref --short @{-1}` complains about no such ref).

Comment: You want to get the name of the branch? Your question says nothing about that... You might want to edit it.

Comment: That's what I meant with "if it was a branch [HEAD] will be on a branch". I'll re-phrase to make it clearer. But basically, I want the same result as in my partial answer

Comment: I feel like the question is still unclear. Do you want the branch name if HEAD was last pointing to a branch indeed, and the SHA otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to be able to read some output so that you, as a user, know what `git checkout -` would do, then you can do

```
git reflog
```

and it will *usually* tell you the right thing.  It will show the `HEAD` reflog, with output like

```
c5d4ede HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to branch
38c594f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from branch to master
c5d4ede HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 
c5d4ede3ffa2633bd7b8b0f19a100832a3b3ac86 to branch
c5d4ede HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to HEAD^
38c594f HEAD@{4}: commit: 2
c5d4ede HEAD@{5}: commit (initial): 1
```

You can see that `HEAD@{1}` is what was last checked out, the abbreviated hash for the commit is `38c594f`, and based on the description it must be that `master` was checked out.

There is one little problem, though.  In this case, the output doesn't show you whether `master` has moved since you were on `master`.  There aren't a lot of ways that would happen, but if you have to be sure, and the `HEAD` reflog shows that a branch would be checked out, then you would follow up with

```
git reflog master
```

to see where `master` is now; because `git checkout -` will checkout the branch, not a specific commit, in this situation.

(In the event that `HEAD@{1}` shows that you were in detached state, you won't have to worry about possible branch moves and you'd know that `chekcout -` would take you to the commit identified in the log.)

If you want something for a script's consumption, that's a tougher problem.  You can get the commit ID you were on with

```
git rev-parse HEAD@{1}
```

But knowing what branch you were on isn't as easy (because a commit could have zero, one, or many branches pointing to it), and without knowing which branch you were on you can't know if the branch might have moved.

It seems that `git` is able to figure this out when executing a `checkout`, but as far as "how", we've reached the edge of my knowledge.  The obvious answer would be for it to use the reflog, but I don't see anything that looks structured enough in the reflog files for that to be correct.

Comment: This is very useful. It is precisely that sort of magic done by `git checkout -` that I would like to use in a script (so reading the reflog is not exactly what I was after)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's how to do it if changing the position of HEAD is not a disqualifier.

```
get_last_head() { 
  local REV; 
  git checkout -q -; 
  REV=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD) || 
  REV=$(git rev-parse HEAD); 
  git checkout -q -; 
  echo $REV; 
}; 
get_last_head
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `rev-parse --symbolic-full-name`, although that means manipulating the output to remove the initial `refs/head/`

```
get_last_head() {
    local REV=$(
        git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1} |
        sed -re 's%^refs/heads/%%' # Not sure how safe this is
    );
    if [ -z "$REV" ]; then REV=$(git rev-parse HEAD); fi
    echo $REV;
}
```