# Not able to loop through directories in a path stored in a variable

Tags: bash

I just don't get it, why I cannot do the thing I just mentioned in the question?

For more clarification, I am trying to loop through all the directories in a certain path, which is stored in any random variable of my choice. Please look at the below script and let me know why the execution doesn't get past the `for` loop beginning statement when I run the script:

```
gpll_allrepos3() {
    export SIMPROJS="/c/Projects/mainproject"
    currPath=$(pwd)
    for repoFolder in $SIMPROJS; do
        echo "RepoFolder: $repoFolder"
        if [[ -d "$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder/.git" && ! -L "$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder/.git" ]]; then
            echo "$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder"
            cd "$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder" && echo "Now inside $SIMPROJS/$repoFolder"
            curr_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
            ## git pull && git pull origin
            ## if [[ "$curr_branch" != "master" ]]; then
                ### Merging master branch as the current branch is feature branch
                git checkout master
                git pull && git pull origin
                git checkout $curr_branch
                git merge master
            ## fi
        fi
    done
    cd $currPath
}
gpll_allrepos3
```

I am not a very good Bash scripter, so any suggestion is appreciated, but please note, I need to be able to run this script from anywhere I choose.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the output of `for repoFolder in $SIMPROJS; do echo "$repoFolder"; done` and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: I did that and it ony printed the parent path and that too, only once, strange, I thought it was gonna loop thro' sub-folders and not the parent path itself..

Comment: That's because you're not giving it anything to glob. Try adding `/*` to the end of your variable.

Comment: Note: you don't need to save `curr_branch`, you can `git checkout -` (shorthand for `git checkout @{-1}`) to checkout the previous branch ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` doesn't iterate over the contents of directories, it iterates over a series of "words" (basically, strings). Thus, this statement:

```
for var in alice bob "jimmy joe" /c/Projects/mainproject; do
```

...will run its contents four times, first with `var` set to "alice", then "bob", then "jimmy joe", then "/c/Projects/mainproject". It doesn't treat any of those as file or directory names, because you didn't ask it to. On the other hand, the shell will expand `/c/Projects/mainproject/*` to a list of files in the directory /c/Projects/mainproject/ (including the path prefix). Thus, you could use:

```
for repoFolder in "$SIMPROJS"/*; do
```

The wildcard string will expand to a series of words (corresponding to the files and directories under /c/Projects/mainproject/), and then `for` will iterate over those.

Note the double-quotes around the variable reference? It's almost always a good idea to do this, otherwise the shell will split the variable's contents into separate words based on spaces (or whatever's in the `IFS` variable), and expand wildcards in the variable's value, and you usually don't want that (and if it happens unexpectedly, it can cause trouble). On the other hand, the `*` has to be *outside* the double-quotes so it'll expand to a list of files, not just be treated as a literal filename.

Also, note that this will iterate over files as well as subdirectories in /c/Projects/mainproject. If you want just subdirectories, use this:

```
for repoFolder in "$SIMPROJS"/*/; do
```

The added trailing slash will restrict it to just matching directories (because a slash at the end of a directory's path makes sense, but at the end of a plain file's path it doesn't). But note that the trailing slash will get included in the resulting paths as well.

Other notes: don't use `"$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder"` etc -- the `repoFolder` variable already includes the path prefix (because it was included in the wildcard string that got expanded), so adding it again will cause trouble. Just use `"$repoFolder"`.

Also, when you use `cd` in a script, you should always include error handling in case it fails for some reason. Otherwise, the script will continue running in the wrong place, probably leading to chaos. You use:

```
cd "$SIMPROJS/$repoFolder" && echo "Now inside $SIMPROJS/$repoFolder"
```

...if this fails (which it will because of the path-doubling problem), it will not print the "Now inside..." message, but will then continue on with everything else. What you should use is something more like this:

```
cd "$repoFolder" || {
    echo "Couldn't cd into $repoFolder, cancelling..." >&2
    return 1
}
```

...which will exit the function rather than blindly continuing in the wrong place.

BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common problems like these; I recommend running your scripts through it, at least until you get more familiar with shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through files in a directory you need to provide a string that can be [expanded to a filename glob](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

Once you have that, your loop variable will contain the entire path, so no need to prefix the original directory name.

Also you can use `pushd` and `popd` to avoid creating your `$currPath` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
simprojs="/c/Projects/mainproject"
for repoFolder in "$simprojs"/*; do
    if [[ -d "$repoFolder/.git" && ! -L "$repoFolder/.git" ]]; then
        pushd "$repoFolder" && echo "Now inside $repoFolder"
        curr_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
        git checkout master
        git pull && git pull origin
        git checkout "$curr_branch"
        git merge master
    fi
done
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

A script seems like overkill for the problem, can use `find`: `find $SOMEPATH -type d -name .git -execdir git checkout master \; -execdir git pull && git pull origin \; -execdir ... \;`.

`find` directories (`-type d`) named ".git" (`-name .git`) in `$SOMEPATH`. For each .git directory run `command` from the subdirectory containing the matched file (`-execdir command \; -execdir command \; -execdir ... \;`).

You don't need to `cd` to the .git directory, you don't need to maintain a stack of directories (e.g. `pushd` and `popd`), etc. One-liner. Note: by default `find` never follows symbolic links (ref. op's `! -L`).