# How can I see on which branch I was before

Tags: git

How can I know which branch I was previously on? More precisely, which branch `git checkout -` will go to?

I would also like to know what more previous branches were, in case the previous one is not the one I want to checkout.

In other words, how to see the 'branch' history? Not the current branch commit history, but the history of branches I checked out.

All I find in my searches are about commit history.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch) that explains about `git checkout -`:

Comment: I would think the reflog has that info. It shows stuff like `HEAD@{4}: checkout: blah`

Comment: It could be, my understanding is that it would go up the current branch commit history, but I realise there is no basis for my assumption

Comment: Absolutely right @evolutionxbox. You can make it an answer, that is totally what I needed. Bonus points for fixing my wrong assumptions about reflog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred method is to use the simple syntax [`@{-1}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em) (thanks [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)).

```sh
git show --decorate -s @{-1}
```

---

*Original answer:*

The reflog does seem to keep a history of where `HEAD` is moved, and looks to be accessible by the `HEAD@{#}` variable.

This however does also include resets, rebases, cherry-picks, and commits. I assume that this is because all of those commands move the `HEAD`.

```sh
104f63b (HEAD -> master, master.bak) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from b2 to master
e97431a (b2) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from b1 to b2
588aa76 (b1) HEAD@{2}: cherry-pick: C6
befdf09 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to befdf09b
80cf3dd HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to b1
104f63b (HEAD -> master, master.bak) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from b2 to master
e97431a (b2) HEAD@{6}: cherry-pick: C7
befdf09 HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to befdf09b
4dd1828 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to b2
104f63b (HEAD -> master, master.bak) HEAD@{9}: commit: C5
be1bfdb HEAD@{10}: commit: C4
07743f7 HEAD@{11}: commit: C3
befdf09 HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from b1 to master
80cf3dd HEAD@{13}: commit: C6
4dd1828 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from b2 to b1
4dd1828 HEAD@{15}: commit: C7
befdf09 HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from master to b2
befdf09 HEAD@{17}: commit: C2
464acc2 HEAD@{18}: commit (initial): C1
```

If checking the reflog is too much [there is a program to help with that](https://github.com/teddywing/git-checkout-history).

Comment: Very simple syntax [`@{-1}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em): `git show --decorate -s @{-1}`

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-1}` is another variant. More info at [man git-rev-parse](https://gitirc.eu/git-rev-parse.html).

Answer (score -2):

just type `history`. It will give you all the previous commands you typed in your shell.

Comment: `history | grep checkout` would be an upgrade, but still, I guess reflog / `@{-n}` is hard to surpass.