# List the history of branches checked out

Tags: git

`git reflog |grep 'checkout: moving'|cut -d\  -f 8` shows me what I am after but I always heard using plumbing for scripting is better than parsing the output of  porcelain commands. What would be the plumbing equivalent here?

Comment: Not a direct answer but might be useful : you can refer to the *Nth* last checked out branch with `@{-N}`, see [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: Yes, this is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7206801/308851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip reflog's formatting entirely, just

```
cut -f2- .git/logs/HEAD | awk '$1=="checkout:" { print $NF }'
```

but I think nobody's bothered making officially-scriptable interfaces for the reflog, branch names are local, arbitrary and ephemeral already, the reflogs for what's been checked out even more so.

Comment: Unlike git reflog which can be run anywhere in the working tree, the command above needs to be run on the top. But it's easy to fix: `cut -f2- $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/logs/HEAD |awk '$1=="checkout:" { print $NF }'` works well and has been added as `ch` to my git toolkit which includes a `git reset --hard` safety net most importantly and makes push sane. https://gist.github.com/chx/3a694c2a077451e3d446f85546bb9278