# Is there git shorthand to reference the current branch I'm on?

Tags: git

I really love the ability to use `-` as [shorthand to refer to the last branch I was on.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch)

I was wondering if there is shorthand to refer to the current branch I am on? For example,

Before

```
$(dev/my_branch)    git push -f origin dev/my_branch
$(dev/my_branch)    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev/my_branch
```

After

```
$(dev/my_branch)    git push -f origin .
$(dev/my_branch)    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/.
```

Comment: As both answers noted, `HEAD` means *the current branch*. However, it also means *the current commit*. It depends on how you ask the question. Use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` or `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to ask the question *what is the **name*** and use `git rev-parse HEAD` to ask the question *what is the **hash ID***.

Comment: The `git push` command is interesting in that it actually needs to ask *both* questions, internally, and will do so.

Comment: Last, note that `@` by itself is a short way to spell `HEAD`. Given that you like `-` for "previous branch name" you might like this one-letter spelling. :-) None of this works for your `--set-upstream-to`, though, which demands that you spell out `origin/dev/my_branch`. I like to use `git push -u origin HEAD` to set it up initially, and then after that, just `git push -f` with no argument to update the current name after a rebase, provided I'm on a branch everyone agrees gets rebased like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git push origin HEAD
```

HEAD will always refer to the latest Commit of your current branch.

**Alternative**:

You can **configure git** to push to the current branch using the following command

```
git config --global push.default current
```

then just do

```
git push
```

this will push the code to your current branch.

Answer (score 4):

The shorthand to refer to the current branch is **--**:

Suppose, you are on a branch called 'feature/old-branch-name`, wishing to rename it.

```
git branch -m -- feature/new-branch-name
```

The current branch was renamed!

Comment: This does not work in other situations.

For example, `git pull origin --`
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

HEAD will refer to the current branch

Comment: Head refers to the current commit not branch.