# What is the mercurial equivalent to `git checkout -`?

Tags: mercurial

What is the mercurial equivalent to [`git checkout -`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207542/2482570)? I want to go to wherever I last was.

I tried `hg checkout -`, but that yields a parse error.

Comment: "I want to go to wherever I last was" -- can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: Sure: what `git checkout -` does.


For example, after `git checkout foo && git checkout bar && git checkout -` one ends up at ref `foo`.

After `hg update foo && hg update bar` what can I type to go back to `foo` without mentioning `foo` directly (to save keypresses and inspecting logs)?.

Comment: Wish I knew more git :(   So after doing just `git checkout foo && git checkout bar` what would be the state of things at that point? Doesn't it basically make the working folders look like whatever was committed at `bar` ?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand the underlying workflow and objective, so that I can think about what the HG equivalent might be.

Comment: @StayOnTarget correct, `git checkout` is roughly `hg update` .

The use case of `git checkout -` is to jump around quickly between different commits. Such as "work on bookmark foo, switch to bookmark bar to look at some code for reference, switch back to where I started easily".

Take `cd` as an anology: if there are too dirs: `dir_foo` and `dir_bar`, one can do `cd dir_foo && cd dir_bar && cd -` and end up at `dir_foo`. `git checkout -` is like `cd -` but for branches instead of directories.

Comment: Would you literally run those commands serially with `&&` ? If so , would it have any effect?

Comment: I would not literally run the commands serially with `&&`. An example use case is "work on bookmark foo, switch to bookmark bar to look at some code for reference, switch back to where I started easily". This is a thing people really do with git - see this StackOverflow answer that references `git checkout -`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207542/2482570 and Unix StackExchange answer about `cd -`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81224/how-to-go-to-the-previous-working-directory-in-terminal

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation, you're answering my questions instead of the other way around :)   I do a similar workflow in HG often as well... wish I could think of a precise way to do what you want however.  As far as I know HG does not maintain any *history* of the *working directory*.  So maybe this is not possible out of the box.

Comment: Incidentally since you mentioned bookmarks - check out `hg topic` sometime, its close to git branches as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one.

The `-` here in Git is shorthand for `@{-1}`, which refers to the *reflog* for `HEAD`.  While Git's branches are much more like Mercurial's bookmarks than anything else, every time you *switch* branches, Git writes an entry to a reflog saying *before switching, the current branch was <name>*.  A subsequent `@{-number}` means *scan through this particular reflog looking for such entries, count until you hit the number-th such entry, and use that branch name as the name here*.  For this to work, the system must maintain this log of `checkout` operations, storing the old name whenever a new name is supplied.  I'm glossing over Git's so-called *detached HEAD* mode here: `@{-number}` refers to both names *and* raw hash IDs.  Mercurial has nothing like Git's "detached HEAD" mode: you're always on some branch.  Mercurial branches are real, solid things, unlike Git's branches, which evaporate while leaving the commits around:  In Git, commits are on *many branches simultaneously*, which is quite nonsensical in Mercurial, but sensible enough in Git, and deleting a branch just takes away *one* of the many names that allow Git to find the commits.

Since Mercurial does not retain a log of each `hg update`, there is no way to retrieve a previous update argument from the log.  [Edit: there is the experimental Journal extension; see [Max Heiber's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911108/what-is-the-mercurial-equivalent-to-git-checkout/67948929?noredirect=1#comment120120975_67948929).]  You could of course write your own little wrapper that runs `hg update` and, if the update succeeds, logs which commit and/or branch was in use just before the update.  This wrapper could then implement the "update back" operation.

Side note: The `hg topics` command that [StayOnTarget mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911108/what-is-the-mercurial-equivalent-to-git-checkout#comment120085892_67911108) is part of the [evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/index.html).  This gives Mercurial the ability to do things Git just can't do.  It's not the same as using Git branches at all.  Mercurial *without* evolve can already do the same things Git can do, and a bit more (because Mercurial branchs are real).  However, the permanance of branches, while attractive at first blush, is in my opinion often a net negative (by which I mean "you should use bookmarks first, and maybe only").  But the evolve extensions are are a feature sorely missing from both Mercurial and Git; they're available in Mercurial, but not part of the standard distributions and require extra user knowledge (see also the [roadmap](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CEDRoadMap) and its links).

Comment: Thanks! A few small corrections: `git checkout -` doesn't go to the previous branch, it goes to wherever `HEAD` was last - which can be any ref, including commits that aren't on any branches. So the paragraphs about differences in branching philosophy between git and hg are probably not relevant.
And `hg`, at least the one I got via homebrew, does have something that seems a lot like `reflog` - `hg journal` (experimental extension): https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension

Comment: @MaxHeiber: that's why I said I was glossing over detached-HEAD stuff. Since Mercurial lacks this concept entirely, there was no point covering it here, but I have a tendency to want to be *technically correct* so I introduced it in this sideways fashion. :-) Separately: I wasn't aware of the Journal extension though, that's kind of handy.